# code asp.net c# oledb, cookies, if else

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, cookies, oledb

Can somebody help understand this code?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database database = new Database();

        OleDbConnection conn = database.connectDatabase();

        if (Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"] == null)
        {
            lbl_leeg.Text = "Er zijn nog geen bestelde artikelen";
        }
        else
        {
            HttpCookie best = Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"];

            int aantal_bestel = best.Values.AllKeys.Length;
            int[] bestelde = new int[aantal_bestel];
            int index = 0;

            foreach (string art_id in best.Values.AllKeys) 
            {
                int aantalbesteld = int.Parse(aantalVoorArtikel(int.Parse(art_id)));

                int artikel_id = int.Parse(art_id); // moet getalletje zijn

                if (aantalbesteld != 0)  
                {
                    bestelde[index] = artikel_id;
                }
                index++;
            }

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT artikel_id, naam, prijs, vegetarische FROM artikel WHERE artikel_id IN (" +
                String.Join(", ", bestelde) + ")";


            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            catch (Exception error)
            {
                errorMessage.Text = error.ToString();
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And there is this part of code i dont really understand:

```
public string aantalVoorArtikel(object id)
    {
        int artikel_id = (int)id;

        if (Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"] != null &&
            Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"][artikel_id.ToString()] != null)
        {
            return Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"][artikel_id.ToString()];
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

Comment: So are you having a problem, or just wanting someone to explain what the code is doing?

Comment: More explaination about the code, i would appreciate a answer for the last bit of code. I cant get a hang of it..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It extracts values from a cookie and builds an int array. (Displays a message if the cookie value is null) The int array is then used as the value for the SQL IN operator when querying the database. The result set is then bound to the GridView.