# Please explain this code to me

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, request

We hit an unexpected error during our school project. Someone took the time and figured out what it was. But when he fixed it he couldn't explain what he did. I hope someone can explain the following line of code:

```
    public string aantalVoorArtikel(object id)
    {
        int artikel_id = (int)id;

        if (Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"] != null &&
            Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"][artikel_id.ToString()] != null)
        {
            return Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"][artikel_id.ToString()];
        }
        else
        {
            return "0";
        }
    }
```

I hope this if enough information to give a line by line explanation.

Comment: Ideally the name of the method should explain what the method does.  However, I don't know what that name means.  Also, side note... If he couldn't explain what he did then he didn't "fix" anything.  He threw some code at it and it looked like the problem went away, that's about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't guess what the original state of the code was nor what was added to resolve the "error".

Comment: How can we know what basic part of c# you do not understand? That's pretty basic code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Comment: There is also a problem with the parameter being an object that is then explicitly cast to an `int`.  First problem in that the calling is "probably" passing an `int` which then has to be boxed into an `object` to send it to this method to then be cast back to an `int` straight away.  Second, if the method accepts an object, anything goes.  It could receive a `string`, `List`, or any other Type and there is no safety or error checking when casting.

Comment: Needs to be closed as a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808888/code-asp-net-c-sharp-oledb-cookies-if-else#comment49671298_30808888

Comment: @TonyHinkle: Good catch. Must be two ... people ... in the same class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code is checking whether a specific item is in the shopping basket and if so, it returns the quantity for that item.

It checks whether there is a shopping basket set in the cookies

```
Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"] != null
```

Then it checks whether an item with id has been added

```
Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"][artikel_id.ToString()] != null
```

If it exists it returns the value of the cookie which represents the quantity

```
return Request.Cookies["BesteldeArtikelen"][artikel_id.ToString()]
```

If not found 0 is returned.